# Integrating over $\delta\left( \mu - \frac{- (t - \tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2}{2 x \tau_2} \right)$ for $-1< \mu < 1$

Tags: integration, inequality, dirac-delta

Suppose $t>0$ and $x>0$ and consider the integral
$$
\int_0^t d \tau_1 \int_0^{\tau_1} d \tau_2 \int_{-1}^{1} d \mu \ \delta\left(\mu - \frac{- (t - \tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2}{2 x \tau_2} \right) f( \tau_1, \tau_2, \mu )
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and $f$ is some well-behaved function. From here it is obvious that I should be integrating over $\mu$, which would let me write the integrand as $\to f\left(\tau_1, \tau_2, \frac{- (t - \tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2}{2 x \tau_2} \right)$. However this can obviously only be done when
$$
-1 < \frac{- (t - \tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2}{2 x \tau_2} < +1
$$
which I think will effect the possible integration ranges for $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. I cannot figure out how to reduce the above inequality in a useful way however.

How would one reduce this inequality into useful bounds for the $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ range?

Comment: Since $-(t - \tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2 \pm 2 x \tau_2$ is a product of two linear factors, the $(\tau_1, \tau_2)$ region defined by the double inequality is a rectangle. Taking $(\tau_1, \tau_2) = ((u + v)/2, (u - v)/2)$ makes the rectangle sides parallel to the coordinate axes, so the triple integral becomes
$$\frac 1 2 \int_{t - x}^{t + x} \int_0^{t - x}
 f {\left( \frac {u + v} 2, \frac {u - v} 2,
  \frac {x^2 - (t - u) (t - v)} {x (u - v)} \right)} dv du
 \hspace {1.5 px} [x < t].$$

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for your answer, the coordinate redefinition works well. I don't understand your statement about $-(t-\tau_1)^2 + \tau_2^2 + x^2 \pm 2 x \tau_2$ being a product of two linear factors:  How does this function being linear in $\tau_2$ imply that the region described is a rectangle? (there is also a $\tau_2^2$ in the expression)